# Rock Paper Scissors, but wait! It's set up differently

Tags: python, python-3.x

Alice and Bob are playing rock-paper-scissors game.

Input Specification
The first line contains one integer N (1≤N≤100) that represents the number of games.
The second line is Alice's shape sequence and third line is Bob's shape sequence.

Output Specification
Two integers separated by a space, representing the number of games won by Alice and the number of games won by Bob.

---

I first made Alice and Bob's shapes in a list using .split() and then I set up a bunch of elif and if statements for each possible scenario. But the problem I'm having is that it is not iterating correctly for example if I input

```
3
rock rock rock 
rock rock paper
```

instead of output being `0, 1` I get `0,0` and I can't seem to figure out why. Here's my code below.

```
games = input()
alice = input()
bob = input()

alice = alice.split()
bob = bob.split()

awin = []
bwin = []
a = 0

while a < len(alice):
    for i in range(len(alice)):
        if alice[i] == "rock" and bob[i] == "rock":
            break
        elif alice[i] == "scissors" and bob[i] == "scissors":
            break
        elif alice[i] == "paper" and bob[i] == "paper":
            break
        elif alice[i] == "rock" and bob[i] == "scissors":
            awin.append('rock beat scissors')
            break
        elif alice[i] == "rock" and bob[i] == "paper":
            bwin.append('paper beat rock')
            break
        elif alice[i] == "paper" and bob[i] == "rock":
            awin.append('paper beat rock')
            break
        elif alice[i] == "paper" and bob[i] == "scissors":
            bwin.append('scissors beat paper')
            break
        elif alice[i] == "scissors" and bob[i] == "paper":
            awin.append('scissors beat paper')
            break
        elif alice[i] == "scissors" and bob[i] == "rock":
            bwin.append('rock beat scissors')
            break
        i += 1
    a+=1

print('output:')
print(awin)
print(bwin)
print(str(len(awin)) + " " + str(len(bwin)))
```

Comment: The first problem is that your `break`s cause the program to break out of the `for` loop, so it will only ever compare the first item. In addition, you don't need to change the value of the `i` inside the for loop, the loop will take care of that and the `while` loop is completely useless.

Comment: You wrote `break` statements which stop the loop whatever the outcome of the first game is; so you only counted the first game. But you counted the first game 3 times because of the outer `while` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a more simplified version of your code:

```
games = input()
alice = input()
bob = input()

alice = alice.split()
bob = bob.split()

awin = []
bwin = []

for i in range(len(alice)):
        # If both players play the same move
        if alice[i] == bob[i]:
            continue
        elif alice[i] == "rock" and bob[i] == "scissors":
            awin.append('rock beat scissors')
        elif alice[i] == "rock" and bob[i] == "paper":
            bwin.append('paper beat rock')
        elif alice[i] == "paper" and bob[i] == "rock":
            awin.append('paper beat rock')
        elif alice[i] == "paper" and bob[i] == "scissors":
            bwin.append('scissors beat paper')
        elif alice[i] == "scissors" and bob[i] == "paper":
            awin.append('scissors beat paper')
        elif alice[i] == "scissors" and bob[i] == "rock":
            bwin.append('rock beat scissors')

print('output:')
print(awin)
print(bwin)
print(str(len(awin)) + " " + str(len(bwin)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have given some direction on the original code. I'm just stopping by to offer an alternative approach that is a little more 'pythonic'...and because coding games like this can be a bit of fun!

This implementation doesn't play the same as code in the original question, but has the advantage of following how the game flows in real life.

```
from collections import defaultdict 

# defaultdict returns 0 (int() initial value) if the key does
# not exist. So, encode contests in format AB where 1 means
# A beats B. All other scenarios default to 0 i.e. B wins.
game = defaultdict(int)
game['RS'] = 1
game['SP'] = 1  
game['PR'] = 1 

num_games = input()
aw,bw = 0,0 

while num_games:
   alice = raw_input('Shape for Alice:')
   bob = raw_input('Shape for Bob:') 
   aw += game[alice + bob]
   bw += game[bob + alice]
   num_games -= 1

print(aw,bw)
```